# Installing Rails -v 3.2.14 Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to install rails on ubuntu 12.04. I installed it, but when I try to use rails new it says rails not installed. After running gem environment I get this output:

```
ben@ben-V5-131:~$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.10
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/ben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334
     - /home/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
ben@ben-V5-131:~$
```

Is the problem that rails might be installed in the global gem path?

Comment: Just a note: I'm not sure Rails 3.2 supports ruby-1.8.7, I'd suggest updating to the latest ruby-2.0.0 release. Just to be sure show what you have in your $PATH variable and check if `/home/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334` (or the global one) actually has rails in it.

Comment: follow the instractions in this link http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 0):

For installing ruby on rails on ubuntu 12.04, please follow following blog:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm

it works for me on ruby 2.0.0 and rails 4.0

my gem environment:

```
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.1.5
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 247) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/tao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/tao/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/tao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/tao/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/tao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247
     - /home/tao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/tao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin
     - /home/tao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin
     - /home/tao/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin
     - /home/tao/.rvm/bin
     - /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin`enter code here`
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
```